# Making 2D arrays / matrix'es in SystemVerilog

Tags: system-verilog

I was making a 2D array in SystemVerilog, but the modelsim compiled with errors, so now my question is why?

Here is the code for the matrix multiply and accumulate unit i am trying to make:

```
module matrix_mac_unit
(//ports

 input  clock,
 input  reset,
 input  enable,
 input  clear,
 input  [7:0] matrix_1 [0:3][0:3],
 input  [7:0] matrix_2 [0:3][0:3],
 output [7:0] result   [0:3][0:3]
);

 logic [7:0] accumulator [0:3][0:3];

//sequential logic
always_ff @(posedge clock) begin
  if (!reset) begin
      accumulator <= 0;
  end
  else if (clear) begin
      accumulator <= 0;
  end
  else begin
      accumulator <= result;
  end

end

//combinational logic
assign result = enable ? matrix_1 * matrix_2 + accumulator : 
accumulator;

endmodule
```

The modelsim says:

> unit.sv(40):(vlog-2110) Illegal reference to net array "matrix_1".
>
> unit.sv(40):(vlog-2110) Illegal reference to net array "matrix_2".
>
> unit.sv(40):(vlog-2990) Illegal operation on unpacked type.
>
> unit.sv(40):(vlog-2110) Illegal reference to memory "accumulator".
>
> unit.sv(40):(vlog-2990) Illegal operation on unpacked type.

So my question is how you you declare a matrix in SystemVerilog?

Comment: Why is there an underscore `_` in your error message but not in your declaration. Show the code that generates the error.

Comment: @dave_59 i updated the descritpition, please have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SystemVerilog does not do matrix multiplication. You'll need to expand the equation out into individual elements. There are many examples out there. Here's one: http://verilogcodes.blogspot.com/2015/11/verilog-code-for-matrix-multiplication.html